# Every Interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

The proof I've been given is

> If not, there is a non-constant continuous $f$ from $I$ to
>   discrete $\{0, 1\}$. Then $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also continuous which contradicts the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Why must $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ also be continuous?

Comment: $f: I \rightarrow \{0,1\} \subset \mathbb R$.  Viewing the space containing the codomain as a subset of a larger set does not affect whether a function is continuous or not.  Continuity is determined by the behavior of the domain.

Comment: I have to wonder though if that proof isn't circular and it is my impression that the Intermediate Value Theorem relies upon the connectedness of intervals in its proof.

Comment: It $is$ circular. I never liked this proof because just as you say, the various proofs of IVT use at some point, the fact that intervals are connected.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion $\{0,1\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous because $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology.

Compositions of continuous functions are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ is not connected, then by definition there are $A$ and $B$ both open such that  $A \cup B=I$, if you consider $f$ such that $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$ than this is a  continuos function by definition, infact in $ \{0,1\} $ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ there is the discrete topology and $ f^{-1}( \{0,1\})=I $ that is open, $ f^{-1}( \{0\})=A $ that is open, $ f^{-1}( \{1\})=B $ that is open and 
$ f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset $ that is open so you have a contraddiction with the IVT. However this demonstration is circular because you have to use the connectedness of $I$ for proving the IVT.